# PHP - How would one go about combining 3 different arrays into one

Tags: php, arrays

So i have 3 different ( yet they share some similarities ) and i would like to combine these into one to perform some calculations

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ï»¿Agent
            [1] => Answered
            [2] => Missed
            [3] => Contribution
            [4] => Per Hour
            [5] => Total Ring Time
            [6] => Mean Ring Time
            [7] => Total Talk Time
            [8] => Mean Talk Time
            [9] => Total Wrap Time
            [10] => Mean Wrap Time
            [11] => Total Session Time
            [12] => Mean Session Time
            [13] => Number of Sessions
            [14] => % Util
            [15] => Agent Hang-Ups
            [16] => Caller Hang-Ups
            [17] => Agent Hang-Ups Percent
            [18] => Caller Hang-Ups Percent
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Amber
            [1] => 16
            [3] => 2.0%
            [4] => 0.2
            [5] => 28.6
            [6] => 1.8
            [7] => 1861.1
            [8] => 116.3
            [9] => 0.0
            [10] => 0.0
            [11] => 234862.2
            [12] => 3403.8
            [13] => 69.0
            [14] => 0.8%
            [15] => 10
            [16] => 6
            [17] => 62.5%
            [18] => 37.5%
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Amie
            [1] => 106
            [3] => 13.5%
            [4] => 3.0
            [5] => 721.7
            [6] => 6.8
            [7] => 12268.0
            [8] => 115.7
            [9] => 0.0
            [10] => 0.0
            [11] => 127011.0
            [12] => 6350.5
            [13] => 20.0
            [14] => 9.7%
            [15] => 54
            [16] => 52
            [17] => 50.9%
            [18] => 49.1%
        )
)
```

Array 2

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ï»¿Agent
            [1] => Answered
            [2] => Missed
            [3] => Contribution
            [4] => Per Hour
            [5] => Total Ring Time
            [6] => Mean Ring Time
            [7] => Total Talk Time
            [8] => Mean Talk Time
            [9] => Total Wrap Time
            [10] => Mean Wrap Time
            [11] => Total Session Time
            [12] => Mean Session Time
            [13] => Number of Sessions
            [14] => % Util
            [15] => Agent Hang-Ups
            [16] => Caller Hang-Ups
            [17] => Agent Hang-Ups Percent
            [18] => Caller Hang-Ups Percent
        )
)
```

Array 3

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ï»¿Agent
            [1] => Answered
            [2] => Missed
            [3] => Contribution
            [4] => Per Hour
            [5] => Total Ring Time
            [6] => Mean Ring Time
            [7] => Total Talk Time
            [8] => Mean Talk Time
            [9] => Total Wrap Time
            [10] => Mean Wrap Time
            [11] => Total Session Time
            [12] => Mean Session Time
            [13] => Number of Sessions
            [14] => % Util
            [15] => Agent Hang-Ups
            [16] => Caller Hang-Ups
            [17] => Agent Hang-Ups Percent
            [18] => Caller Hang-Ups Percent
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => (7312
            [1] => 1
            [3] => 0.0%
            [4] => 459.8
            [5] => 0.0
            [6] => 0.0
            [7] => 0.4
            [8] => 0.4
            [9] => 0.0
            [10] => 0.0
            [11] => 7.8
            [12] => 2.6
            [13] => 3.0
            [14] => 5.5%
            [15] => 1
            [17] => 100.0%
            [18] => 0.0%
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Amber
            [1] => 414
            [2] => 9
            [3] => 9.3%
            [4] => 6.3
            [5] => 1880.1
            [6] => 4.4
            [7] => 65209.8
            [8] => 157.5
            [9] => 240.4
            [10] => 0.6
            [11] => 234862.2
            [12] => 3403.8
            [13] => 69.0
            [14] => 27.8%
            [15] => 290
            [16] => 124
            [17] => 70.0%
            [18] => 30.0%
        )
```

So in this example i have 3 arrays, all have the same first initial array.  But these arrays can differ in size and they may not share the same people in in. 
People can also be in different places so i.e.

```
Array 1 : Common -> Amber -> Amie
Array 2 : Common -> 
Array 3 : Common -> 7312 -> Amber ->Amie
```

Now the final array should look like

```
Array 4 : Common -> 7312 -> Amber -> Amie
```

All the values from all arrays should also be combined so i.e:

```
Amber 1st array / 1st value : 16
Amber 2nd array / 2nd value : 414

Amber final array value : 414 + 16 = 430
```

Hopefully i have made question clear.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Looping through the arrays seems to be the thing to do... But without code we can't really help...

Comment: Also what can you use to relate the data? I don't see any kind of consistent identifier.

Comment: @Salketer its not about what i have/have not tried... what i have more trouble with is the logical approach to this. Not necessary code wise.

Comment: @prodigitalson i was thinking to replace the key for all ararys with corresponding values from 1st common array. So instead of having [0] as the key for first element i would have [Agent] as the first element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you sum up all the info you got, remove the headers. Then rebuild a new array with the info consolidation.

```
//merge all arrays, remove the first element, it is headers.
$my_total_array = array_merge(
    array_splice($array1,1),
    array_splice($array2,1),
    array_splice($array3,1)
);

$myagents = array();
foreach($my_total_array as $agent){
    if(!isset($myagents[$agent[0]])){
         //Never met the agent, add them.
         $myagents[$agent[0]] = $agent;
    }else{
         //We already seen the agent, do maths.
         $myagents[$agent[0]][1]+=$agent[1];
         //TODO: Apply consolidation rules for other fields.
    }
}
//Put the headings back at the beggining.
array_unshift($myagents,$array1[0]);
print_r($myagents);
```

I hope this helps.

EDIT: From PHP Docs

> Merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values
>   of one are **appended to the end of the previous one**. It returns the
>   resulting array.
>
> If the input arrays have the **same string keys**, then the later value
>   for that key will **overwrite the previous one**. If, however, the arrays
>   contain **numeric keys**, the later value **will not overwrite the original**
>   value, but will be appended.

Comment: Thanks for input. However i thought array_merge function when merges two arrays with the same key but different value, the value from first array is being overridden by the 2nd value ?

Comment: Edited to add some part of the PHP doc about the array_merge... You could have merged them yourself if you prefer but in your example, no need to.

Comment: Ahh.. ok i see now, i have to read docs more carefully ;) as i believed that the values will be overridden which would have make the hole thing useless. Upvoted - accepted :)

Comment: Note: the most trouble i had with this was to actually figure out how to approach this in a most sensible and effective way :)